# Python user input matches both the list and file

Tags: python-3.x, string, if-statement, match

Hot to create a python code that user input matches the list of word and file.

for example

```
    list = ["banana", "apple"]

    file = open("file_path", "r")
    search_word = input("Search the word you want to search: ")
    for search_word in file.read()
    and search_word in list

    print("Search word is in the list and in the file")
    else:
    print("Search word is not matches")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the search word is not in the list then don't see a need to search the contents of the file for a match since it fails the first condition. Can test that condition and if false then don't need to search the file.

You could do a simple string test if it is found in the file contents.

```
if search_word in data:
    print("match")
```

However, words that contain the search word will also match (e.g. pineapple would match with apple).

You can use a regular expression to check if the word is contained anywhere in the file. The `\b` metacharacter matches at the beginning or end of a word so for example *apple* won't match the word *pineapple*. The `(?i)` flag does a case-insensitive search so the word *apple* matches *Apple*, etc.

You can try something like this.

```python
import re

list = ["banana", "apple"]
search_word = input("Search the word you want to search: ")    
if search_word not in list: 
    # if not in list then don't need to search the file
    found = False
else:
    with open("file_path", "r") as file:
        data = file.read()
    found = re.search(fr'(?i)\b{search_word}\b', data)

# now print results if there was a match or not
if found:
    print("Search word is in the list and in the file")
else:
    print("Search word does not match")
```

Comment: Hi @uka let me know if this solves your problem.